# Prove that the farthest point among a set of points(in 2-d plane) should lie on the convex hull

Tags: algorithm, graph, convex-hull

The question speaks for itself. It is required to prove that given a set of 2-d points, the pair of points farthest from each other must lie on the convex hull.

Comment: A point A is on the convex hull if there exists another point B in the set of points P for which all points in P are on the same side of the line AB.

Comment: Even better: a point A is on the convex hull if there exists a line through it for which all points in P are on the same side.

Comment: For the two points farthest away from each other in a set, A and B, you can prove that this holds for the lines perpendicular to A and B, through A and B.

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs here, though.

Comment: @jgroenen Hmmm....all right, that helps. Put it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A point *A* is on the convex hull if there exists a line through it for which all points in your set of points are on the same side of this line. For the two points farthest away from each other in a set, *A* and *B*, you can prove that this holds for the lines perpendicular to *A* and *B*, through *A* and *B*.

Answer (score 0):

Adding few more details to the answer above.

**Claim 1**: The point(P) with minimum y-coordinate will always lie on the convex hull of a set of N points.

**Proof**: Let's assume that the point(*P*) with minimum y-coordinate lies strictly inside the convex hull. Then there would exist a point(*Q*) on the convex hull such that Qy < Py, thereby contradicting the assumption that that point P has the minimum y-coordinate.

**Claim 2**: A point A is on the convex hull if and only if there exists a line through it for which all points in the set of points are on the same side of the line.

**Proof**: (Only if condition) Consider the point *P* with minimum y coordinate. From Claim 1, point *P* lies on the convex hull and the line passing through *P* parallel to x-axis satisfies the criteria that all other points of set S lies above it. Now for any other point(*P'*) on the convex hull, we can rotate the coordinate axis such that P' has the minimum y-coordinate.

(If condition) Let the point P be such that there exists a line(*L*) for which all points in the set are on one side. Rotate the coordinate axis in way that slope of *L* becomes zero, thereby making P a point with minimum y-coordinate. Now use Claim 1 to show that it is indeed a point on the convex hull.

The **Claim 2** can now be utilized as to prove that the farthest pair would indeed lie on the convex hull as mentioned in the previous answer.